# Biq query Export Job configuration - double quotes in strings

Tags: google-bigquery

Below is the export job configuration to export biq query table data to storage in csv format. What is happening is, if a string column has data with double quotes in it, when it is extracted, I get two double quotes. Say for example

```
Column_data : xxdsadsa "sdfsada" adfadfsaa

Exported_column_data : xxdsadsa ""sdfsada"" adfadfsaa
```

Here is the Job config

```
job_data = {
        'configuration': {
            'extract': {
                'sourceTable': {
                    'projectId': xxxxx,
                    'datasetId': xxxxxx,
                    'tableId': xxxx
                },
                'printHeader': False,
                'fieldDelimiter': '\t',
                'compression': 'GZIP',
                'destinationUris': [gs://xxxxxxx],
                'destinationFormat': CSV,

            }
        }
    }

service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http_auth)
job_collection = service.jobs()
insert_response = job_collection.insert(projectId=project_id, body=job_data).execute(http=http)
```

Is there a way to supress getting two double quotes while extracting from table to storage. I have seen the job config extract properties and couldnt find any. Appreciate the help

Comment: How are you running your code? Just tested it here and it worked normally, not sure why this is happening to you.

Comment: I am using python to run it. I have added little more info to the original code , may be that might help you. Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: I am getting the same using the BigQuery web UI.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned I have the same issue with double quotes using BigQuery web UI. The single quote however works perfectly. As workaround, you can convert all double quotes to single quote.

You can also check the [configuration.load.quote](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.quote) property.

**Preview on BigQuery:**

[image]

**Exported CSV table:**

[image]

Comment: did you get an answer to this? we are also facing similar issue.. any pointers will help